# Inequation critical points error

Tags: inequality

I have this exercise:
$$3x^2-7x+4>0$$
Step 1:
$$(3x-4)(x-1)>0$$
Step 2: My critical points are $\frac{4}{3}$ and $1$
Step 3: The problem is that there is no number between $\frac{4}{3}$ and $1$, so I cannot draw the grafic, any hint please.
Step 4: We have conclude this hypothesis
**hypothesis 1:**       $$3x-4>0$$
        $$3x>4$$
        $$x>\frac{4}{3}$$ and
        $$3x-4<0$$
        $$3x<4$$
        $$x<\frac{4}{3}$$
**hypothesis 2:**    $$x-1>0$$
        $$x>1$$ and
        $$x-1<0$$
        $$x<1$$
@Emilio @Karl I don't know how can we go from my hypothesis to your answers, please explain.

Comment: There are infinitely many real numbers between $4/3$ and $1$.

Comment: What do you want to do?
to draw the graph or find range of values for x?

Comment: @SubhasishBasak I want to find range of values for x

Comment: The critical points you mention are the $x$ intercepts of the function $y=f(x)$ The inequality you mention is the part of the graph where $f(x)>0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

note that $\dfrac{4}{3} > 1$. So the inequality is verifed by any $x$ external to the interval $[1,\dfrac{4}{3}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=(3x-4)(x-1)$

This is quadratic so we know the general shape of $y=f(x)$

You have identified the $x$ intercepts of $y=f(x)$.

You need only choose another suitable $x=a$ value an identify the sign of $f(a)$ and hence picture a rough sketch of $y=f(x)$

Choose $x=0\implies f(0)>0$

Note that $0$ is outside of the interval between the critical points and the graph is positive there.

As a consequence the function must be negative between the critical points owing to the shape of quadratic graphs.

The solution is therefore $x<1$ and $x>4/3$